# Disable Spring Cloud security

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-cloud, spring-security-oauth2, spring-cloud-security

I tried to disable Spring security in Spring Could using this configuration:

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = { ...... },
        exclude = SecurityAutoConfiguration.class)
public class Application {

    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

When I make a request I get: `An expected CSRF token cannot be found`

and into prompt I get:

`01:14:35.799 [boundedElastic-1] DEBUG DefaultWebSessionManager[lambda$createWebSession$3:94] - Created new WebSession. 01:14:35.862 [boundedElastic-1] DEBUG HttpWebHandlerAdapter[traceDebug:91] - [375ab2a1] Completed 403 FORBIDDEN`

Do you know into the latest Spring Cloud how to disable Spring Security?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable it using properties file:
`security.enable.csrf=false`

Or Alternatively:

You can disable `csrf` by extending `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` class and overriding `configure` method. Refer to [this spring document](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.0.CI-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/csrf.html).

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends
   WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
      .csrf().disable();
  }
}
```

Comment: I get `The bean 'springSecurityFilterChain', defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/security/reactive/ReactiveManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration.class], could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class] and overriding is disabled.` and also `spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true` but again I get the same issue: `An expected CSRF token cannot be found` Any other solution?

Comment: try security.enable.csrf=false or security.enable.csrf: false in propertis/yaml file.

Comment: I added it but again the same issue occur.

Comment: If you add it in properties file and you are using  `ReactiveManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration`  just to disable `csrf` then you don't need it. You can delete that class and try.